# How to run a cron job on every Monday, Wednesday and Friday?

Tags: cron

How can one run a cron job for every Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 7:00 pm?

Answer (score 192):

Here's my example crontab I always use as a template:

```
# Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To run my cron job every Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 7:00PM, the result will be:

```
0 19 * * 1,3,5 nohup /home/lathonez/script.sh > /tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

[source](https://github.com/lathonez/utils/blob/master/crontab/example.crontab)

Comment: You should avoid linking to external resources, as they might go away and make your answer useless.

Comment: This is more a paste from documentation than an actual answer. You may edit your post to show the actual answer (0 19 * * 1,3,5)

Comment: How about spring cron job expression which has 6 characters instead of 5?

Answer (score 48):

Use crontab to add job

```
  crontab -e
```

And job should be in this format:

```
  00 19 * * 1,3,5 /home/user/somejob.sh
```

Comment: the command is "crontab -e" for editing, "-l" stands for "list"

Answer (score 23):

The rule would be:

```
0 19 * * 1,3,5
```

I suggest that you use **http://corntab.com** for having a very convenient GUI to create your rules in the future :)

Comment: fyi, `corntab.com` is not a typo. That's really how the website is spelled.

Comment: The corntab site is no longer available. But I found this one which allowed me validate the syntax of a cron directive: https://crontab.guru

Answer (score 17):

This is how I configure it on my server:

```
0  19  *  *  1,3,5 root bash /home/divo/data/support_files/support_files_inc_backup.sh
```

The above command will run my script at 19:00 on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday.

NB: For cron entries for day of the week (dow)

```
0 = Sunday
1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday
3 = Wednesday
4 = Thursday
5 = Friday
6 = Saturday
```

Answer (score 13):

Use this command to add job

```
crontab -e
```

In this format:

```
0 19 * * 1,3,5 /path to your file/file.php
```

Answer (score 8):

The following expression will solve your problem

```
0 19 * * 1,3,5
```

Comment: A question in an answer?  This was indeed correct, of course.  But formatted more like a comment.

Answer (score 8):

Use crontab to add job

```
0 0 9 ? * MON,WED,FRI *
```

The above expression will run the job at 9 am on every mon, wed and friday.
You can validate this in : http://www.cronmaker.com/