# How can i schedule a project to run every Monday in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have a project in Jenkins and i want to run every Monday ( the project has 10 jobs ).
Is there any way to set the schedule to run all the project ( not a specifique job ) ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260837/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-every-monday-wednesday-and-friday/31261110

Answer (score 0):

You schedule a script to execute [Bulk Builder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=46337152#content/view/46337152)

> Bulk builds can be easily triggered by external scripts or  processes,
>
> ```
>  curl -u username:password -X POST http://localhost:8080/bulkbuilder/build -d action=immediate_build -d build=all
> ```

Comment: Hi, i have a question. And how can i set to only run the second job, after the first finished?