# How to trigger a Airflow task only when new partition/data in avialable in the AWS athena table using DAG in python?

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-athena, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I have a scenerio like a below :

1. Trigger a `Task 1` and `Task 2` only when new data is avialable for them in source table ( Athena). Trigger for Task1 and Task2 should happen when a new data parition in a day.
2. Trigger `Task 3` only on the completion of `Task 1` and `Task 2`
3. Trigger `Task 4` only the completion of `Task 3`

[image]

**My code**

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.contrib.sensors.aws_glue_catalog_partition_sensor import AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from utils import FAILURE_EMAILS

yesterday = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(1), datetime.min.time())

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email': FAILURE_EMAILS,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('Trigger_Job', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

Athena_Trigger_for_Task1 = AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor(
    task_id='athena_wait_for_Task1_partition_exists',
    database_name='DB',
    table_name='Table1',
    expression='load_date={{ ds_nodash }}',
    timeout=60,
    dag=dag)

Athena_Trigger_for_Task2 = AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor(
    task_id='athena_wait_for_Task2_partition_exists',
    database_name='DB',
    table_name='Table2',
    expression='load_date={{ ds_nodash }}',
    timeout=60,
    dag=dag)

execute_Task1 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='Task1',
    postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
    sql="/sql/flow/Task1.sql",
    params={'limit': '50'},
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    dag=dag
)

execute_Task2 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='Task2',
    postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
    sql="/sql/flow/Task2.sql",
    params={'limit': '50'},
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    dag=dag
)



execute_Task3 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='Task3',
    postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
    sql="/sql/flow/Task3.sql",
    params={'limit': '50'},
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    dag=dag
)

execute_Task4 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='Task4',
    postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
    sql="/sql/flow/Task4",
    params={'limit': '50'},
    dag=dag
)



execute_Task1.set_upstream(Athena_Trigger_for_Task1)
execute_Task2.set_upstream(Athena_Trigger_for_Task2)

execute_Task3.set_upstream(execute_Task1)
execute_Task3.set_upstream(execute_Task2)

execute_Task4.set_upstream(execute_Task3)
```

What is best optimal way of achieving it?

Comment: are you having any problems with this solution ?

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen,Sometimes the `Task1` and `Task2` goes in loop . For me data get loaded in the Athena source table 10 AM CET.

Comment: going on a loop you mean, airflow retries Task1 and Task2 many times until it suceeds?

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, yup exactly

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, its get timeout and fails after 5 mins

Comment: I wrote what I think might be the problem, take a look and see if it makes sense

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, I just added comment to your answer. Basically I want trigger the task based on event rather than time. I know the data in source table arrives after 10 AM but not sure exact time. So as soon as a new data partition is avaialble then need to trigger .  Dependecy is after 10 AM and data ispartition is avialable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212227/discussion-between-bernardo-stearns-reisen-and-pankaj).

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, It worked . Also I f i want to run it only Mon to Sat what be cron format

Comment: happy to know! check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260837/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-every-monday-wednesday-and-friday

Comment: the code of days of the week is `day of week (0 - 7) - sunday =0 or 7`  so your format would be '0 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6'

Comment: let me know if it makes sense, consider giving the bounty if it worked also :)

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, I didnt know  how to award the bounty  :)

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, hey do know trigger a DAG based on success on another DAG.If so can let me know. Here in the above question `Trigger Job` should run only on the success of  DAG called `Job A`

Comment: try this: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html?highlight=external_task_sensor#module-airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor

Comment: @Bernardostearnsreisen, let me explore. My question is extact same 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514887/how-to-trigger-a-dag-on-the-success-of-a-another-dag-in-airflow-using-python?noredirect=1#comment108819462_61514887'

Comment: I understood better now, I answered there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question addresses two major problems:

1. forgetting to configure the `schedule_interval` in an explicit way so @daily is setting up something you're not expecting.
2. How to trigger and retry properly the execution of the dag when you depend on an external event to complete the execution

***the short answer: set explicitly your schedule_interval with a cron job format and use sensor operators to check from time to time***

```
default_args={
        'retries': (endtime - starttime)*60/poke_time
}
dag = DAG('Trigger_Job', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 10 * * *')
Athena_Trigger_for_Task1 = AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor(
     ....
    poke_time= 60*5 #<---- set a poke_time in seconds
    dag=dag)
```

where `startime` is what time your daily task will start, `endtime` what is the last time of the day you should check if an event was done before flagging as failed and `poke_time` is the interval your `sensor_operator` will check if the event happened.

***How to address the cron job explicitly***
whenever you are setting your dag to `@daily` like you did:

```
dag = DAG('Trigger_Job', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')
```

from the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html), you can see you are actualy  be doing:
`@daily - Run once a day at midnight`

Which now makes sense why you're getting timeout error, and fails after 5 minutes because you set `'retries': 1` and `'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)`. So it tries running the dag at midnight, it fails. retries again 5 minutes after and fail again, so it flag as failed.

So basically @daily run is setting an implicit cron job of:

```
@daily -> Run once a day at midnight -> 0 0 * * *
```

The cron job format is of the format below and you set the value to `*` whenever you want to say "all".

`Minute Hour Day_of_Month Month Day_of_Week`

So @daily is basicly saying run this every: minute 0 hour 0 of all days_of_month of all months of all days_of_week

So your case is run this every: minute 0 hour 10 of all days_of_month of all_months of all days_of_week. This translate in cron job format to:

```
0 10 * * *
```

***How to trigger and retry properly the execution of the dag when you depend on an external event to complete the execution***

1. you could trigger a dag in airflow from an external event by using the command `airflow trigger_dag`. this would be possible if some how you could trigger a lambda function/ python script to target your airflow instance.
2. If you can't trigger the dag externally, then use a sensor operator like OP did, set a poke_time to it and set a reasonable high number of retries.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also if  I want trigger the tasks based on event rather than time i.e as soon new data partition is avialable in the source ` AWS Athena Tables` next task should triggered. Then how do I schedule. Is my current code apt enough.

Comment: @pankaj, I see only two alternatives. I don't know much about aws athena, but you could trigger a dag in airflow from an external event by using the command `airflow trigger_dag`. this would be possible if some how you could trigger a lambda function/ python script to target your airflow instance.

Comment: the other alternative is more or less what you are doing, because you don't have an event based trigger you need to periodically check if this event happened. So a using this current solution would be set a cron job for a range of hours run the dag in a high frequency of minutes... many will fail but it will be able to catch fairly quickly after the event happens

Comment: @Bernado, I have figured out package in Airflow called `AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor` along along with airflow command `{{ds_nodash}}` for the partition  exits.  My question then how to schedule this .

Comment: @Benado, Can you have look at my code where I have implemented above mentioned check and give your inputs

Comment: @pankaj , you can see from the docs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.6/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/aws_glue_catalog_partition_sensor/index.html

Comment: you have an parameter `poke_interval (int) – Time in seconds that the job should wait in between each tries`

Comment: @pankaj let's move the discussion to the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212228/discussion-between-bernardo-stearns-reisen-and-pankaj).