# how to set cronjob for Monday and Wednesday?

Tags: cron, days

I saw some answers but I am not getting understand so thats why I am posting question here .

Here is my cron example

```
0  0  */2    *  *
```

How can I set cronjob to run on Monday and wednesday in a week ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a cron job on every Monday, Wednesday and Friday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260837/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-every-monday-wednesday-and-friday)

Comment: @MikeSlinn thank you