# AWS cron every Sunday and Wednesday

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

How can I run a cron job at 2am UTC at every Sunday and Wednesday on AWS.

```
0 2 * * SUN,WED *
```

The time is fine, just the days seem to be the wrong format (getting `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid` via serverless). But all resources I can find do only state ranges of days, how to select single ones?

Comment: The days "seem to be the wrong format"?

Comment: @jarmod `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid` via serverless

Comment: Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260837/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-every-monday-wednesday-and-friday).

Comment: @jarmod I tried `0 2 * * 3,7 *`, does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cron should look like this:

```
0 2 ? * SUN,WED *
```

Or:

```
0 2 ? * 1,4 *
    ^
    Day of month is wrong
```

Your issue is with the Day of month.

Check the result in EventBridge

[image: EventBridge]

Comment: So what would Monday and Tuesday be?

Comment: So Sunday starts at 1? Not Monday?

Comment: Does not seem to work `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid`

Comment: @jarmod I fix it, the problem seems with `Day of month`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer, what do you mean by "day of the month is wrong".

Comment: The 3rd placeholder is the Day of the month

Answer (score 0):

From AWS documentation:

> Limitations
>
> You can't specify the Day-of-month and Day-of-week fields
> in the same cron expression. If you specify a value or a * (asterisk)
> in one of the fields, you must use a ? (question mark) in the other.
>
> Cron expressions that lead to rates faster than 1 minute are not
> supported.

The correct way should be:

```
 0 2 ? * SUN,WED *
```